# execute another xampp version on windows

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp7.2.6 to D:\xampp and then installed xampp5.6.12 to D:\xampp5612 in windows10.
When I click to start xampp5 apache, the xampp7 apache will start.

[image]

The log shows the following error when I execute xampp5612/xampp-xontrol.exe before I click anything.

```
Apache Service detected with wrong path
Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
Found Path: "D:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
Expected Path: "d:\xampp5612\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
Problem detected!
Port 80 in use by ""D:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 10428!
Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
Problem detected!
Port 443 in use by ""D:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 10428!
Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
 MySQL Service detected with wrong path
Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
Found Path: D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=d:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
Expected Path: d:\xampp5612\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=d:\xampp5612\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
```

How can I fix the "Found Path" to start xampp5.6.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution to this issue is to start Apache manually. Look for a file called `apache_start.bat` in e.g. `D:\xampp5612`.

If this file doesn't exist, then you can simply create an appropriate `.bat` file yourself:

*ex. `apache_start.bat` (xampp)*

```
@echo off
echo Please close this command only for Shutdown
echo Apache 2 is starting ...

D:\xampp5612\apache\bin\httpd.exe

if errorlevel 255 goto finish
if errorlevel 1 goto error
goto finish

:error
echo.
echo Apache could not be started
pause

:finish
```

---

*This batch file is taken directly from XAMPP with only minor alterations. The important part is to specify the correct path to `httpd.exe` (Apache).*

---

Note that you will need to keep the command window spawned by this batch file open as long as you wish Apache to run (i.e. closing the window will shut down Apache). You can, of course, minimize it without issue (as desired).

Comment: After editing apache\bin\httpd.exe to D:\xampp5612\apache\bin\httpd.exe. This absolute path works. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to assist. =)